TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] when sending Email from Gmail
Here is the simple test code which cannot consistently reproduce the issue:
    smtp_conn=smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')

    smtp_conn.login(my_email, my_app_password)
    smtp_conn.sendmail(
        from_addr=my_email,
        to_addrs=my_receiver_email,
        msg='Subject: Test\n\nThis is a test email.'
    )

    smtp_conn.quit()

I'm using app password to sending from a service Gmail and the code is running well for months.
Yesterday, I've noticed a strange phenomenon: when using smtplib to log into my Gmail account and send emails, a large number of timeout exceptions occur, with only a few requests going through successfully. It seems like Google might be imposing some kind of restriction on the connections.
smtplib.SMTP_SSL seems to have some problem when connecting to gmail.
The timeout issue cannot be consistently reproduced, but it seems that the same code is limited to sending only one or two emails per minute. It looks like Google no longer supports sending emails via smtplib. I've found some solutions, and they all suggest using Gmail's official client to handle this. However, I have customer service email addresses from multiple sites, and some of them need to send emails using non-Gmail addresses. I also can't accept using third-party components to relay emails, and I don't want to implement multiple sending strategies that increase code complexity. Is it still possible to continue using smtplib?
Or is there a better solution?
